# Unable to create BitBucket OAuth Consumer

Tags: jenkins, oauth, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I am trying to install the [BitBucket Status Notifier Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/bitbucket-build-status-notifier) and as part of its documentation it is mentioning to create `OAuth Consumer`.

However I am not able to find the option in any setting, even if I am a super admin.

I am using hosted BitBucket v 4.7.1.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works only with BitBucket Cloud only. Look at the wiki page that you mentioned [BitBucket Status Notifier Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/bitbucket-build-status-notifier)

> This plugin aims at the Atlassian-hosted BitBucket Cloud solution, not
>   BitBucket Server (formerly known as Stash).